# how to see the correct month not just february (closed)

Tags: java, if-statement

make a program in which depending on the introduced month and year through screen , it prints the name of the month and the days the month has. sorry x my englsih

I TRIED TO CHANGE THE ORDER OF THE MONTH FEBRUARY CODE TO CHECK IF THE PROBLEM WAS IN THE LEAP YEAR OR NOT

```
    int year;
    int nmes;
    System.out.println("introduce un mes de 1 a 12");
    nmes = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("introduce año");
    year = scan.nextInt();  
    if ( year == 1 ) {
        System.out.println("año"+year+"enero, dias : 31");
    }else if ( year == 3 ) {
        System.out.println("año"+year+"marzo, dias : 31");
    }else if ( year == 4 ) {
        System.out.println("año"+year+"abril, dias : 30");
    }else if ( year == 5 ) {
        System.out.println("año"+year+"mayo, dias : 31");
    }else if ( year == 6 ) {
        System.out.println("año"+year+"junio, dias : 30");
    }else if ( year == 7 ) {
        System.out.println("año"+year+"julio, dias : 31");
    }else if ( year == 8 ) {
        System.out.println("año"+year+"agosto, dias : 31");
    }else if ( year == 9 ) {
        System.out.println("año"+year+"septiembre, dias : 30");
    }else if ( year == 10 ) {
        System.out.println("año"+year+"octubre, dias : 31");
    }else if ( year == 11 ) {
        System.out.println("año"+year+"noviembre, dias : 30");
    }else if ( year == 12 ) {
        System.out.println("año"+year+"diciembre, dias : 31");}
    else if((nmes == 2)&&((year % 4 == 0)&&((year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0))) ) {
            System.out.println(year +"mes febrero , dias: 29");
    }       else {
                System.out.println(year +"mes febrero , dias: 28");
            }}
```

}

ESPERABA QUE AL INTRODUCIR EL NUMERO DE MES ME SALIESE EL MES QUE CORRESPONDIESE PERO SIEMPRE SALE FEBRERO
ESTO ES LO QUE MUESTRA LA CONSOLA
introduce un mes de 1 a 12
6
introduce año
2005
2005mes febrero , dias: 28

Comment: Please, use English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `year` with `nmes` in all `if` checks (except the check for 2) i.e. it should be like

```
if ( nmes == 1 ) {
    System.out.println("año"+nmes+"enero, dias : 31");
}else if ( nmes == 3 ) {
    System.out.println("año"+nmes+"marzo, dias : 31");
}else if ( nmes == 4 ) {
    System.out.println("año"+nmes+"abril, dias : 30");
}else if ( nmes == 5 ) {
    System.out.println("año"+nmes+"mayo, dias : 31");
}else if ( nmes == 6 ) {
    System.out.println("año"+nmes+"junio, dias : 30");
}else if ( nmes == 7 ) {
    System.out.println("año"+nmes+"julio, dias : 31");
}else if ( nmes == 8 ) {
    System.out.println("año"+nmes+"agosto, dias : 31");
}else if ( nmes == 9 ) {
    System.out.println("año"+nmes+"septiembre, dias : 30");
}else if ( nmes == 10 ) {
    System.out.println("año"+nmes+"octubre, dias : 31");
}else if ( nmes == 11 ) {
    System.out.println("año"+nmes+"noviembre, dias : 30");
}else if ( nmes == 12 ) {
    System.out.println("año"+nmes+"diciembre, dias : 31");}
```